# Matching latitude / longitude points within polygons

Tags: python, neural-network, coordinates, shapefile, geopandas

I am trying to figure out how to match coordinate points to polygons. The coordinate points come from a *.csv* dataset about wildfires and each point corresponds to a fire. I am trying to merge this with a shapefile with information about vegetation and other characteristics. The shapefile contains polygons whereas the *.csv* only contains one column for latitude and one for longitude.

In the end, I would like to use this dataset to predict the severity of a fire using neural networks.

So far, I have tried :

- Converting the *.csv* to a GeoPandas DataFrame and *sjoin* both datasets using the following code :

```
from shapely.geometry import Point
from shapely.geometry.polygon import Polygon
from geopandas.tools import sjoin

point = df_fires             #GeoDataFrame
poly  = data                 #shapefile with the polygons

pointInPolys = sjoin(point, poly, how='left')
```

However, this doesn't work due to the size of the *df_fires* DataFrame (~10m rows).

- Using a simple loop :

```
for i in range(len(data)):
  for j in range(len(df_fires)):
     df_fires['geometry'].values[j].within(data['geometry'].values[i])
```

However, I had the same issue, i.e. the dataset is too large.

I don't want to match on exact coordinates but on whether or not each single lat / lon point is contained within each polygon.

*df_fires.csv* looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8yKo.png) and *nativevegetationareas.shp* looks something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RikBu.png).

Comment: `sjoin` is optimised, your loop is not. What do you mean "it does not work"? You run out of memory, got some error or it just takes ages?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and apologies for not being precise enough. I have no ram nor error issues but it takes ages. I run the code on Colab Pro and the runtime is disconnected before it reaches completion.

Comment: You can try to split your `df_fires` into multiple smaller parts and do the join separately (could be even multiprocessed). The issue here is the size of the dataset, the code itself works. I am not aware of better implementation so far. There is some work in GeoPandas on this, but not finished yet.